# How to solve a system of differential equation like this one

Tags: differential-equations

I am trying to solve a complicated system of differential equations which can be reduced to a MWE of this kind:

```
NDSolve[{c'[x] == 10 d[x, y] + D[d[x, y], x], D[d[x, y], {x,2}] + D[d[x, y], {y,2}] == 1, c[0] == 0, DirichletCondition[d[x, y] == 0, True]}, {c, d}, {x, 0,   1}, {y, 0, 1}]
```

There is one function $c$ that only depends on a variable $x$, while the other function $d$ depends on both $x,y$. Trying to execute that code I get the error

> "There are fewer dependent variables, {d[x,y]}, than equations, so \ the system is overdetermined."

How can I solve it?

I use version 11.3 for Linux if needed

Comment: Can you treat c[] formally as a function of x and y, even though as a function of y it is constant?

Comment: @MichaelE2 I think it is possible

Comment: @cvgmt   `d[x, y] ` must satisfy `{D[d[x, y], {x, 2}] + D[d[x, y], {y, 2}] == 1, D[10 d[x, y] + D[d[x, y], x], y] == 0}`.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe split the question into two differential equations.

**Update**

```
Clear["`*"];
sol = NDSolve[{D[d[x, y], {x, 2}] + D[d[x, y], {y, 2}] == 1, 
   DirichletCondition[d[x, y] == 0, True]}, d, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]
NDSolve[{D[c[x, y], x] == 10 d[x, y] + D[d[x, y], x], 
   c[0, y] == 0} /. sol, c, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]
```

**Original**

```
Clear["`*"];
sol = NDSolve[{D[d[x, y], {x, 2}] + D[d[x, y], {y, 2}] == 1, 
   DirichletCondition[d[x, y] == 0, True]}, d, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]
With[{y = .1}, 
 NDSolve[{c'[x] == 10 d[x, y] + D[d[x, y], x], c[0] == 0} /. sol, 
  c, {x, 0, 1}]]
```

Comment: Solution `c[x,y]` should fullfill `Derivative[0,1][c][x,y]==0`

Comment: @UlrichNeumann How do I add that condition?

Comment: @mattiav27 Actually I don't know. My intention was to show that the solution given by  cvgmt isn't the one you are looking for.